# powershell run from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

In the text file `List.txt` I want to delete the quotation marks and save in `ListF.txt`

I can run the following code in the powershell console:

```bsh
(Get-Content List.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"','' } | Set-Content ListF.txt
```

However I can't run the same command with cmd:

```
powershell.exe  -command "{(Get-Content List.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"','' } | Set-Content ListF.txt}"
```

I am very grateful for all the help!

Comment: i think you will need to use the 4th example in the help. put a `& ` between the 1st quote and the opening `{`.

Comment: Not good. I got the answer 'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: please add that exact command and the error to your Question so others won't pester you with repeats of my question. [*grin*] i'm out of ideas - i will go back to lurking. good luck!

Comment: You need to escape the `"` passed to `-replace`, otherwise `cmd` interprets it as a string terminator

Comment: Exact command and the error:
C:\1>powershell.exe  -command "{(Get-Content List.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"','' } | Set-Content ListF.txt}"
'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape some special characters as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987973/powershell-run-from-cmd#comment109636214_61987973) says.

This is how cmd.exe works, but I cannot explain why.

### with quotes

```
powershell.exe -command "(Get-Content List.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '""','' } | Set-Content ListF.txt"
powershell.exe -command "(Get-Content List.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\"', '' } ^| Set-Content ListF.txt"
```

about `|` escaping

```
:: escape `|` until `"` has its pair
echo "1 | 2 " ^| 3 ^| " 4 | 5"

:: every `|` needs escaping because `"` does not have its pair
echo "1 | 2 " ^| 3 ^| 4 ^| 5"

:: no escape
echo "1 | 2 "" | 3 | 4 | 5"
```

### without quotes

```
powershell.exe -command (Get-Content List.txt) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\"', '' } | Set-Content ListF.txt
powershell.exe -command (Get-Content List.txt) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '""""', '' } ^| Set-Content ListF.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Look Ma, no quotes or pipes.  "set-content path value".

```
powershell set-content listf.txt ((get-content list.txt) -replace [char]34)
```

[char]34 is doublequote:

```
[int][char]'"'

34
```